# Why does my macro not work (completely new to python)

Tags: python, keyboard-events

So, I'm trying to write a macro that holds down the left mouse button and the w - key for me. It doesn't throw any errors, but when I press "m" it doesn't start pressing w and LMB, as I intend for it to do.

Here's my code:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

toggle = False

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("M"):
            toggle = not toggle
            break
    except:
        break
    
while toggle: 
    pyautogui.press("W")
    pyautogui.mouseDown()
```

Comment: Add some `print` statements so you can see if it's getting out of the first loop.

Comment: it looks like you are not going outside of the first loop

Comment: I don't know the framework, but checking through the API my first guess would be to use the lower-case 'm' instead of 'M'. Maybe 'M' refers to "shift+m"?